# Calculate running balance in mysql select query and view

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view

My simple table named material with this columns:

```
mat_id       mat_name      stock_in       stock_released    date
1             alloy          30                0            feb13
2             steel          15                0            feb13
3             alloy          0                 3            feb14
```

How can I generate it or calculate it as:

```
mat_id       mat_name      stock_in       stock_released    Balance         date
1             alloy          30                0               30           feb13
2             steel          15                0               15           feb13
3             alloy          0                 3               15           feb14
```

here is my existing code but there is something wrong with the balance because it totals everything disregarding the material name:

```
SELECT 
    `material`.`mat_id`,
    `material`.`mat_name`,
    `material`.`stock_in`,
    `material`.`stock_released`,

    @Balance := @Balance + `material`.`stock_in` - `material`.`stock_released` AS `Balance`,
    `material`.`date`
FROM `material`, (SELECT @Balance := 0) AS variableInit
WHERE mat_name = mat_name
ORDER BY `material`.`mat_id` ASC
```

How can it create view out of this?

Comment: You can't in MySQL.  It has both variables and a subquery in the `from` clause.  Go back to your previous question and look at my answer.  That could be put into a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this data, the query that gets the running balance is:

```
SELECT m.`mat_id`, m.`mat_name`, m.`stock_in`, m.`stock_released`,
       (select sum(stock_in) - sum(stock_released)
        from material m2
        where m2.mat_name = m.mat_name and
              m2.mat_id <= m.mat_id
       ) as balance,
      m.`date`
FROM `material` m
ORDER BY m.`mat_id` ASC;
```

This you can put into a view.

Comment: how about when i have my supplier_id in my material column and must match with same supplier_id from supplier table and display supplier_name sir?

Comment: Then you will add another condition, `m2.supplier_name = m.supplier_name` into the subquery.

Comment: is this right sir? 
`SELECT m.`mat_id`, m.`mat_name`, s.`sup_name`, m.`stock_in`, m.`stock_released`,
       (select sum(stock_in) - sum(stock_released)
        from material m2, supplier s2
        where m2.mat_name = m.mat_name and
              m2.mat_id <= m.mat_id
              m2.supplier = s2.sup_id
       ) as balance,
      m.`date`
FROM `material` m, `supplier` s, 
ORDER BY m.`mat_id` ASC`